# PyCharm won't run the Discord module although it is already installed

Tags: python, pycharm, discord

I am a Pycharm beginner as I have switched from spyder. Now, after moving to Pycharm there are new problems.

As some may know, Python is suitable for making discord bots. I used pip install in the terminal to install the discord package, and then started making the code. Once I run it, the console returns:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'`

For reference here is the code:

```
    # Marble Police
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands

    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print("Marble Police has been dispatched!")

    client.run({BOT TOKEN})
```

If you want additional info, ask me down below.

Comment: just see your project interpreter and install module in it and run that python interpreter

Comment: open the built in terminal interface in PyCharm and do the pip install discord, just to ensure you're installing it in the right virtualenv. And before that make sure you have the right interpreter selected for the project that you want (lower right corner).

Comment: okay that problem was solved, but more problems

Comment: We need more information on your environment. Are you certain that you installed the library to the same Python installation you're using to run the program?

Comment: oh i already solved all the problems

Answer (score 0):

`pip install discord.py`

Checkout https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/

Comment: This looks more like it should be a comment.

Comment: Nope, nothing helpful

Answer (score 0):

Open "Command Prompt" and write this:

**Windows:**

```
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

**Linux/macOS:**

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```